# Sockets leaked in windows not shown in netstat and tcpview

Tags: windows, sockets, network-programming, netstat, sysinternals

Is it possible that windows leaks sockets connection and these sockets are not shown in tcpview and netstat?

After running a few applications that perform many network connections, my windows machine enters a state in whitch it in not able to open any new socket connection. Even to itself (localhosts).
For example, telnet to a local application failed because windows can't create new sockets.
Closing and restarting the network applications does not helps. Only full windows restart solves the problem.

netstat (& tcpview) indicates that there are only some dozens of connections.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're guessing. What is the error message when you "can't create new sockets"? That will tell you whether it's socket leaks or another problem such as port exhaustion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible for those apps to miss leaked connections. Something else is going on.  Maybe you are not looking at their detailed views, like seeing closed sockets that are in `TIME_WAIT` state.  If you cannot open new socket connections, you mostly likely are encountering **port exhaustion**.  Wait some time for ports to time out and become available again.  Or stop wasting ports in the first place.