# Spring Boot HelloWorld not working on IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, spring-boot, ubuntu

I am trying to run a Hello World application with Spring Boot on IntelliJ IDEA. I have the following code:

```
package com.example.springbootexample;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootExampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootExampleApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

After building and running the code I get the following error message:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Web server failed to start. Port 8080 was already in use.

Action:

Identify and stop the process that's listening on port 8080 or configure this application to listen on another port.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Trying to identify the process that uses the port `8080` I run `lsof -i :8080`, but I get a blank output. What could the problem be?

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: the problem is that that port is already in use. So either figure out what is using that port and stop that process, or use another port

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56499928/web-server-failed-to-start-port-8080-was-already-in-use-spring-boot-microservi

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106561/finding-the-pid-of-the-process-using-a-specific-port

Answer (score 0):

Probably you already launched the application before? Check in one of the IntelliJ's `Services` tab (I assume it's IntelliJ you're using) if it displays the logging output of the same application already launched.

If it's blocking, you could either change the proprty server port in your `application.properties` file:

`server.port=8089`

Then you can start again and it should work

Answer (score 0):

There are following things you can do here:

1. If you are running your code with command like **mvn spring-boot:run** then go to terminal section and close the running by **ctrl+c**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvn6J.png)
2. Change your port in **application.properties** file with command server.port=9090[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeTYu.png).

Comment: Please update descriptions of links to screenshots.