# Uvicorn gives "access is denied" in Anaconda Prompt

Tags: python, anaconda, fastapi, uvicorn

**Problem**

I have two conda virtual environments. One can run uvicorn commands such as `uvicorn main:app --reload` to run [the example code from the FastAPI tutorial](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/first-steps/), but the other environment returns `Access is denied.` for each uvicorn command.

**What I have tried**

The second (not working one) has the exact same versions of uvicorn, fastapi, and python installed and I'm using the same anaconda prompt. Hence it's not a problem of access rights on the underlying folder or admin rights, because in that case both environments should not work in the same prompts (right?).

I'm looking for a difference in both environments, but given that only fastapi and uvicorn are required to run Fast API code, I'm not sure what to try next.

**Question**

Are there additional requirements for running a FastAPI app, beyond the fastapi and uvicorn packages that could cause this problem and/or are there perhaps other matters I should look into?

Comment: Do you have the full error message? If the port is in use / reserved, you might get an access denied error message - are you sure the port that uvicorn tries to use is actually available? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48478869/cannot-bind-to-some-ports-due-to-permission-denied

Comment: The full error message is: 'Acces is denied.' There is no more info. Also I don't suspect it's a port-related issue given that it works with the same command in the same prompt for the other venv.