# TCP client on Windows cannot bind() to port < 1023

Tags: windows, winapi, winsock, winsock2

I'm doing some testing with a TCP client on Windows 10 (10.0-19045) but due to firewall restrictions I need to run my experiments from a local port < 1024 (not negotiable).

I thought that this was no problem... but `bind()` fails with "address in use" (yes, I checked netstat, no one is there) for any port < 1023.
Then I checked `netsh int ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp` and the same for IPv6, noone is using those ports.

This *feels* like the "restricted port range" (1-1023) on UNIX/Linux, where only "root" can do a `bind()` with a local port < 1023, but this is Windows, and even as "Administrator" this still fails.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/default-dynamic-port-range-tcpip-chang
talks about a "... well-known ports that are used by services and applications...", but I do not know where to set that (for a Cygwin process).

Does anyone know what is going on? Is there a way around this?

Comment: any reason for using a port lower than `1024`?

Comment: @ElvisAdomnica *"not negotiable"* seems to communicate in no unclear terms that there is. One need not know the reason to understand the problem statement.

Comment: @IInspectable the reason for using a port lower that 1024 could actually give more context to the question. For instance, the question states that it needs to use that port due to firewall restrictions, so one can maybe come up with some workaround.

Comment: also, to debug this I would try a few things: bind to a higher port to make sure that I don't have some errors in my code, I would try to disable Firewall to see if things work, etc.

Comment: also, I would disable Hyper-V

Comment: here are some similar issues presented: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48478869/cannot-bind-to-some-ports-due-to-permission-denied